# Divide two dataframes with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, division

I have two dataframes : `df1` and `df2`

`df1`:

```
TIMESTAMP           eq1 eq2 eq3
2016-05-10 13:20:00  40  30  10
2016-05-10 13:40:00  40  10  20
```

`df2`:

```
TIMESTAMP           eq1 eq2 eq3
2016-05-10 13:20:00  10  20  30
2016-05-10 13:40:00  10  20  20
```

I would like to divide `df1` by `df2` : each column of `df1` by all column of `df2` to get this result `df3` :

```
TIMESTAMP           eq1        eq2        eq3
2016-05-10 13:20:00  40/(10+10) 30/(20+20) 10/(30+20)
2016-05-10 13:40:00  40/(10+10) 10/(20+20) 20/(30+20)
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), but before [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from both columns `TIMESTAMP`:

```
df1.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)

print (df1.div(df2).reset_index())
            TIMESTAMP  eq1  eq2       eq3
0 2016-05-10 13:20:00  4.0  1.5  0.333333
1 2016-05-10 13:40:00  4.0  0.5  1.000000
```

EDIT by comment:

```
df1.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)
print (df2.sum())
eq1    20
eq2    40
eq3    50
dtype: int64

print (df1.div(df2.sum()).reset_index())
            TIMESTAMP  eq1   eq2  eq3
0 2016-05-10 13:20:00  2.0  0.75  0.2
1 2016-05-10 13:40:00  2.0  0.25  0.4
```

Comment: Yes, I had assumed `TIMESTAMP` was the index.

Comment: Yes, if it first columns are `indexes`, solution is simplier `df3 = df1.div(df2)`

Comment: @jezrael thak you for your reply, but I made an error, can you please check my post  edit? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This should work if `TIMESTAMP` is not the index:

```
>>> df1.set_index('TIMESTAMP').div(df2.set_index('TIMESTAMP').sum()) 
                     eq1   eq2  eq3
TIMESTAMP                          
2016-05-10 13:20:00    2  0.75  0.2
2016-05-10 13:40:00    2  0.25  0.4
```

If `TIMESTAMP` is the index, then simply this:

```
df1.div(df2.sum())
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander , but I made an error, can you please check my post edit? Thank you